# How in Objective-C to reference parent UIViewController from prototype cell?

Tags: ios, uitableview, unwind-segue

I have a slide menu. It is implemented using component `SWRevealViewController`. To implement it I have 1 main `UIViewController` (`VC`) - `SWRevealViewController`. I have **menu** `VC` and I have `push segues` to navigate to different **menu's** `VCs`.

For the menu I use prototype cells with custom class for each menu.

My problem is that I need to call `unwind segue` to go to **login** `VC`, using `alert view`. To do that I try usual method `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"unwSegReturnToLogin" sender:self];` on positive answer from the `alert view` (inside custom class for `exit` cell). I have such method declared in my **login** `VC`. I receive error during the compilation:

```
No visible @interface for 'tvcellExitMenuItem' declares 
the selector 'performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:'
```

I suspect that the problem is that `self` in my case is `table cell` and that is not `UIViewController`.

How to refer parent `VC` if this is the case?

If not, please tell me where I am wrong in the logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A subview shouldn't have to know about its parent viewController. Instead, a common pattern that fits your need is the **delegate** pattern : define a delegate property & protocol for your cells' class.

```
// your cell class header might look like this

@class MyCellClass;
@protocol MyCellDelegate

- (void)onCellSelected:(MyCellClass *)cell;

@end

@interface MyCellClass

@property (nonatomic, weak) id<MyCellDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

For example, if your viewController is also your `UITableViewDatasource` , then in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` you can set your cell's delegate to `self`, and call the segue methods in delegate method.

```
- (void)onCellSelected:(MyCellClass *)cell
{
    // retrieve cell indexPath
    NSIndexPath *cellIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];

   // using indexPth, retrieve cell's data

   // push segue with data selected
}
```

Of course, this is only an example, and there are other corrects ways to do that.